# server hangup magento2 apache 2.4

Tags: apache, magento2, php-7.0

I am running magento2 appication on php 7.0.32 with apache2.4 but frequently i am getting server hangup.
[server hangup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iLeg.png)

I am not able to find root cause if any one facing the same let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: run this command and see what it says grep -i maxclient /var/log/httpd/error_log* (grep your apache log file)

Comment: you might want to read this thread and give it another try https://serverfault.com/questions/149936/apache-crash-hangup-doesnt-serve-requests

Comment: I have already tried the same but still same issue i am facing